# Detect if the internet connection is offline?

Tags: javascript, ajax, offline, connectivity, internet-connection

How can I detect if the internet connection is offline in JavaScript?

Comment: If you can or already use websockets - websockets have a Close Event which must be called if the user lost the connection to the server.

Comment: This reminds me of the 90s when all you had to do was declare image events with image = new Image();image.onload=onloadfunction;image.onerror=onerrorfunction;then set the image.src="image.gif?"+Math.random(); I think that still works today.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

[Almost all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status) now support the [`window.navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine) property, and the corresponding `online` and `offline` window events. Run the following code snippet to test it:

```js
console.log('Initially ' + (window.navigator.onLine ? 'on' : 'off') + 'line');

window.addEventListener('online', () => console.log('Became online'));
window.addEventListener('offline', () => console.log('Became offline'));

document.getElementById('statusCheck').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('window.navigator.onLine is ' + window.navigator.onLine));
```

```html
<button id="statusCheck">Click to check the <tt>window.navigator.onLine</tt> property</button><br /><br />
Check the console below for results:
```

Try setting your system or browser in offline/online mode and check the log or the `window.navigator.onLine` property for the value changes.

Note however this quote from [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine):

> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return `true`. So while **you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a `false` value**, **you cannot assume that a `true` value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet**. You could be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters that are always "connected." Therefore, if you really want to determine the online status of the browser, you should develop additional means for checking.
>
> In Firefox and Internet Explorer, switching the browser to offline mode sends a `false` value. Until Firefox 41, all other conditions return a `true` value; since Firefox 41, on OS X and Windows, the value will follow the actual network connectivity.

(emphasis is my own)

This means that if `window.navigator.onLine` is `false` (or you get an `offline` event), you are guaranteed to have no Internet connection.

If it is `true` however (or you get an `online` event), it only means the system is connected to some network, at best. It does not mean that you have Internet access for example. To check that, you will still need to use one of the solutions described in the other answers.

<sub>I initially intended to post this as an update to [Grant Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189457/525036), but it seemed too much of an edit, especially considering that the 2014 update was already [not from him](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/189457/revisions).</sub>

Comment: I recently had the opportunity to work a little bit on offline behaviour. The events are great to use, BUT ios safari will create problems. When you turn of the internet on your phone the offline/online events will be delayed by up to 2 seconds and that can be problematic for visual rendering reasons, as you can't predict the future. That's just something I wanted to mention and might help someone.

Comment: While vpn is connected then if we disconnect internet then window.navigator.onLine does not work

Comment: @Sagar I checked in Firefox and Chrome, if I unplug the cable while connected to my work VPN, they both quickly detect the deconnection. They don't wait for the VPN to reconnect to report an online status though – as I indicated in the answer, `online` just means you have some sort of connection, not that you have internet access. I took this opportunity to put a snippet in my answer to test it.

Comment: Should be selected answer!

Comment: In addition to this answer, corresponding to the quote from Mozilla. If you really want to make sure he's connected to the "internet" and not only the "local area network LAN", you can send a small ping request (an HTTP get request) to any webserver in the world, like Google, Twitter, or even your own website. In case the response ended with a status code of success such as 200, then this means he's connected to the internet, else, he's not.

Comment: @Normal yes, this is what I mention in the last paragraph.

Comment: @imike it appears to be now

Answer (score 163):

You can determine that the connection is lost by making **failed XHR requests**.

The standard approach is to **retry the request** a few times.  If it doesn't go through, **alert the user** to check the connection, and **fail gracefully**.

**Sidenote:** To put the entire application in an "offline" state may lead to a lot of error-prone work of handling state.. wireless connections may come and go, etc.  So your best bet may be to just fail gracefully, preserve the data, and alert the user.. allowing them to eventually fix the connection problem if there is one, and to continue using your app with a fair amount of forgiveness.

**Sidenote:** You could check a reliable site like google for connectivity, but this may not be entirely useful as just trying to make your own request, because while Google may be available, your own application may not be, and you're still going to have to handle your own connection problem.  Trying to send a ping to google would be a good way to confirm that the internet connection itself is down, so if that information is useful to you, then it might be worth the trouble.

**Sidenote**: *Sending a Ping* could be achieved in the same way that you would make any kind of two-way ajax request, but sending a ping to google, in this case, would pose some challenges.  First, we'd have the same cross-domain issues that are typically encountered in making Ajax communications.  One option is to set up a server-side proxy, wherein we actually `ping` google (or whatever site), and return the results of the ping to the app. This is a **catch-22** because if the internet connection is actually the problem, we won't be able to get to the server, and if the connection problem is only on our own domain, we won't be able to tell the difference. Other cross-domain techniques could be tried, for example, embedding an iframe in your page which points to google.com, and then polling the iframe for success/failure (examine the contents, etc).  Embedding an image may not really tell us anything, because we need a useful response from the communication mechanism in order to draw a good conclusion about what's going on.  So again, determining the state of the internet connection as a whole may be more trouble than it's worth.  You'll have to weight these options out for your specific app.

Comment: Now in 2012 you can check the variable navigator.onLine ;)

Comment: navigator.online/offline is unreliable as well, for the very same reasons. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181080/how-to-detect-online-offline-event-cross-browser

Comment: You may want to check out [Offline.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline), an open-source library built for just this purpose.

Comment: Reliability issues aside (all solutions suffer from that issue), `navigator.onLine` is definitely the best one now that [it's cross-browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status).

Comment: `"One option is to set up a server-side proxy, wherein we actually ping google (or whatever site), and return the results of the ping to the app"`. It should **not be stated as a possible solution** to examine. Even If I had a connection to my server I want to check whether, I , can access google, not my server.

Answer (score 60):

IE 8 will support the [window.navigator.onLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304129%28VS.85%29.aspx#status_improvements%29) property.

But of course that doesn't help with other browsers or operating systems. I predict other browser vendors will decide to provide that property as well given the importance of knowing online/offline status in Ajax applications.

Until that happens, either XHR or an `Image()` or `<img>` request can provide something close to the functionality you want.

**Update (2014/11/16)**

Major browsers now support this property, but your results will vary.

Quote from [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine):

> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return `true`. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a `false` value, you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. You could be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters that are always "connected." Therefore, if you really want to determine the online status of the browser, you should develop additional means for checking.
>
> In Firefox and Internet Explorer, switching the browser to offline mode sends a `false` value. All other conditions return a `true` value.

Comment: navigator.onLine is part of HTML5 -- other browsers already have development versions that provide it -- it's already available in Firefox 3 today.

Comment: -but unfortunately not available in earlier versions of IE, which we're often required to support.

Comment: navigator.onLine shows the state of the browser and not the actual connection. So u can have ur browser set to be onLine but it would actually fail because the connection is down. navigator.onLine will only be false if the browser is set to offline browsing.

Comment: if I turn off WI-FI on my Nexus7, page still says that navigator.onLine is TRUE. Bad...

Answer (score 47):

```js
if (navigator.onLine) {
  alert('online');
} else {
  alert('offline');
}
```

See [`onLine` Basic usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine#basic_usage)

Comment: It returns always TRUE if on browser.

Comment: Well first i was trying to disable ONLY LAN, but it was always returning TRUE. So when i disabled all networks (LAN2, Virtual Box etc.) it returned FALSE.

Comment: This answer duplicates several existing answers from 3 years before.

Comment: its not checking the internet connectivity, it checking only the LAN connectivity alone

Comment: Worked for me in HTML 5, JavaScript, in mac book (using wifi) even worked in mobile. but issue is- when wifi on it returns TRUE each time even I off wifi vice-versa.

Comment: It always returns true in all browsers.

Comment: It always return TRUE if internet is connected but browsing is off. We need to check both conditions. Is there any idea?

Comment: According to the MDN documentation for `navigator.onLine`, found at [Navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine), you can see changes in the network state by listening for the events on `window.ononline` and `window.onoffline`.

Comment: onLine always returns true even if you just have hot-spot active. onLine just means that you are connected to ANY network. (ononline and onoffline mean just the same)

Comment: If I disconnect from the network, it still says that I am online.

Comment: @Slavcho, but why is that?

Answer (score 40):

There are a number of ways to do this:

- AJAX request to your own website. If that request fails, there's a good chance it's the connection at fault. The [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) documentation has a section on [handling failed AJAX requests](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxError#callback). Beware of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) when doing this, which may stop you from accessing sites outside your domain.
- You could put an `onerror` in an `img`, like `<img src="http://www.example.com/singlepixel.gif" onerror="alert('Connection dead');" />`.

This method could also fail if the source image is moved / renamed, and would generally be an inferior choice to the ajax option.

So there are several different ways to try and detect this, none perfect, but in the absence of the ability to jump out of the browser sandbox and access the user's net connection status directly, they seem to be the best options.

Answer (score 17):

As olliej said, using the `navigator.onLine` browser property is preferable than sending network requests and, accordingly with [developer.mozilla.org/En/Online_and_offline_events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events), it is even supported by old versions of Firefox and IE.

Recently, the WHATWG has specified the addition of the `online` and `offline` events, in case you need to react on `navigator.onLine` changes.

Please also pay attention to the link posted by Daniel Silveira which points out that relying on those signal/property for syncing with the server is not always a good idea.

Comment: UPDATE: As of 2015 it seems to be working in most browsers, see [caniuse  chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status) and [article](https://davidwalsh.name/detecting-online)

Answer (score 12):

```
window.navigator.onLine
```

is what you looking for, but few things here to add, first, if it's something on your app which you want to keep checking (like to see if the user suddenly go offline, which correct in this case most of the time, then you need to listen to change also), for that you add event listener to window to detect any change, for checking if the user goes offline, you can do:

```
window.addEventListener("offline", 
  ()=> console.log("No Internet")
);
```

and for checking if online:

```
window.addEventListener("online", 
  ()=> console.log("Connected Internet")
);
```

Comment: You have to be careful with `onLine`. Browsers define the state of being online very differently. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine.

Comment: Also this is only reliable if you are making requests. Just turn off your wifi or unplug your ethernet and check this property. Still true.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [$.ajax()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)'s `error` callback, which fires if the request fails. If `textStatus` equals the string "timeout" it probably means connection is broken:

```
function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // typically only one of textStatus or errorThrown 
  // will have info
  this; // the options for this ajax request
}
```

From the [doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options):

> **Error**: A function to be called if the request
>   fails. The function is passed three
>   arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object,
>   a string describing the type of error
>   that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred.
>   Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout",
>   "error", "notmodified" and
>   "parsererror". This is an Ajax Event

So for example:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "keepalive.php",
   success: function(msg){
     alert("Connection active!")
   },
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       if(textStatus == 'timeout') {
           alert('Connection seems dead!');
       }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 10):

The HTML5 Application Cache API specifies navigator.onLine, which is currently available in the IE8 betas, WebKit (eg. Safari) nightlies, and is already supported in Firefox 3

Comment: As discussed on another answer, this doesn't actually work as expected. You can have no internet and `navigator.onLine` will still return `true`.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question has already been answered but i will like to add my 10 cents explaining what's better and what's not.

### Window.navigator.onLine

I noticed some answers spoke about this option but they never mentioned anything concerning the caveat.

This option involves the use of "[window.navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)" which is a property under Browser Navigator Interface available on most modern browsers. It is really not a viable option for checking internet availability because firstly `it is browser centric` and secondly `most browsers implement this property differently`.

> **In Firefox:** The property returns a boolean value, with `true` meaning online and `false` meaning offline but the caveat here is that
> "`the value is only updated when the user follows links or when a script requests a remote page.`" Hence if the user goes offline and
> you query the property from a js function or script, the property will
> always return `true` until the user follows a link.
>
> **In Chrome and Safari**: If the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other
> conditions return true. So while you can assume that the browser is
> offline when it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true
> value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. You
> could be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer
> is running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet
> adapters that are always "connected".

The statements above is simply trying to let you know that browsers alone cannot tell. So basically this option is unreliable.

### Sending Request to Own Server Resource

This involves making HTTP request to your own server resource and if reachable assume internet availability else the user is offline. There are some few caveats to this option.

1. No server availability is 100% reliant, hence if for some reason your server is not reachable it would be falsely assumed that the user is offline whereas they're connected to the internet.
2. Multiple request to same resource can return cached response making the http response result unreliable.

If you agree your server is always online then you can go with this option.

Here is a simple snippet to fetch own resource:

```
// This fetches your website's favicon, so replace path with favicon url
// Notice the appended date param which helps prevent browser caching.
fetch('/favicon.ico?d='+Date.now())
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok)
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');

   // At this point we can safely assume the user has connection to the internet
        console.log("Internet connection available"); 
  })
  .catch(error => {
  // The resource could not be reached
        console.log("No Internet connection", error);
  });
```

### Sending Request to Third-Party Server Resource

We all know CORS is a thing.

This option involves making HTTP request to an external server resource and if reachable assume internet availability else the user is offline. The major caveat to this is the [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) which act as a limitation. Most reputable websites blocks CORS requests but for some you can have your way.

Below a simple snippet to fetch external resource, same as above but with external resource url:

```
// Firstly you trigger a resource available from a reputable site
// For demo purpose you can use the favicon from MSN website
// Also notice the appended date param which helps skip browser caching.
fetch('https://static-global-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/hp-neu/sc/2b/a5ea21.ico?d='+Date.now())
  .then(response => {
  // Check if the response is successful
    if (!response.ok)
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');

// At this point we can safely say the user has connection to the internet
        console.log("Internet available"); 
  })
  .catch(error => {
  // The resource could not be reached
        console.log("No Internet connection", error);
  });
```

So, Finally for my personal project i went with the 2nd option which involves requesting own server resource because basically there are many factors to tell if there is "Internet Connection" on a user's device, not just from your website container alone nor from a limited browser api.

Remember your users can also be in an environment where some websites or resources are blocked, prohibited and not accessible which in turn affects the logic of connectivity check. The best bet will be:

- Try to access a resource on your own server because this is your users environment (Typically i use website's favicon because the response is very light and it is not frequently updated).
- If there is no connection to the resource, simply say "Error in connection" or "Connection lost" when you need to notify the user rather than assume a broad "No internet connection" which depends on many factors.

Answer (score 9):

an ajax call to your domain is the easiest way to detect if you are offline

```
$.ajax({
      type: "HEAD",
      url: document.location.pathname + "?param=" + new Date(),
      error: function() { return false; },
      success: function() { return true; }
   });
```

this is just to give you the concept, it should be improved.

E.g. error=404 should still mean that you online

Answer (score 7):

I had to make a web app (ajax based) for a customer who works a lot with schools, these schools have often a bad internet connection I use this simple function to detect if there is a connection, works very well!

I use CodeIgniter and Jquery:

```
function checkOnline() {
    setTimeout("doOnlineCheck()", 20000);
}

function doOnlineCheck() {
    //if the server can be reached it returns 1, other wise it times out
    var submitURL = $("#base_path").val() + "index.php/menu/online";

    $.ajax({
        url : submitURL,
        type : "post",
        dataType : "msg",
        timeout : 5000,
        success : function(msg) {
            if(msg==1) {
                $("#online").addClass("online");
                $("#online").removeClass("offline");
            } else {
                $("#online").addClass("offline");
                $("#online").removeClass("online");
            }
            checkOnline();
        },
        error : function() {
            $("#online").addClass("offline");
            $("#online").removeClass("online");
            checkOnline();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it is a very simple way.

```
var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?");
if (x) {
  if (navigator.onLine == true) {
    return true;
  }
  alert('Internet connection is lost');
  return false;
}
return false;
```

Comment: onLine doesn't mean that there is an internet connection.
According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

```if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true```

Answer (score 4):

The problem of some methods like `navigator.onLine` is that they are not compatible with some browsers and mobile versions, an option that helped me a lot was to use the classic `XMLHttpRequest` method and also foresee the possible case that the file was stored in cache with response `XMLHttpRequest.status` is greater than 200 and less than 304.

**Here is my code:**

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 //index.php is in my web
 xhr.open('HEAD', 'index.php', true);
 xhr.send();

 xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

 function processRequest(e) {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
         //If you use a cache storage manager (service worker), it is likely that the
         //index.php file will be available even without internet, so do the following validation
         if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
             console.log('On line!');
         } else {
             console.log('Offline :(');
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a client-side solution to detect if the internet was down or my server was down. The other solutions I found always seemed to be dependent on a 3rd party script file or image, which to me didn't seem like it would stand the test of time. An external hosted script or image could change in the future and cause the detection code to fail.

I've found a way to detect it by looking for an xhrStatus with a 404 code. In addition, I use JSONP to bypass the CORS restriction. A status code other than 404 shows the internet connection isn't working.

```
$.ajax({
    url:      'https://www.bing.com/aJyfYidjSlA' + new Date().getTime() + '.html',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout:  5000,

    error: function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.status == 404) {
            //internet connection working
        }
        else {
            //internet is down (xhr.status == 0)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work as of 10-5-2016 not sure why just don't want other peoples' time to be wasted.

Comment: I don't think so it will work for forbidden and bad request errors :)

Answer (score 3):

How about sending an opaque http request to google.com with no-cors?

```
    fetch('https://google.com', {
        method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'no-cors',
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e)
    })
```

The reason for setting no-cors is that I was receiving cors errors even when disbaling the network connection on my pc. So I was getting cors blocked with or without an internet connection. Adding the no-cors makes the request opaque which apperantly seems to bypass cors and allows me to just simply check if I can connect to Google.

FYI: Im using fetch here for making the http request.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch

Answer (score 2):

My way.

```
<!-- the file named "tt.jpg" should exist in the same directory -->

<script>
function testConnection(callBack)
{
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML +=
        '<img id="testImage" style="display: none;" ' +
        'src="tt.jpg?' + Math.random() + '" ' +
        'onerror="testConnectionCallback(false);" ' +
        'onload="testConnectionCallback(true);">';

    testConnectionCallback = function(result){
        callBack(result);

        var element = document.getElementById('testImage');
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }    
}
</script>

<!-- usage example -->

<script>
function myCallBack(result)
{
    alert(result);
}
</script>

<a href=# onclick=testConnection(myCallBack);>Am I online?</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

modern typescript approach:

```
/**
 * @example
 * const isOnline = await isGoogleOnline();
 */
async function isGoogleOnline(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // approach taken from https://github.com/HubSpot/offline/blob/master/js/offline.js#L223
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.onerror = () => {
            // calling `reject` basically means `throw` if using `await`.
            // Instead, we'll just resovle with `false`. (https://www.swyx.io/errors-not-exceptions)
            resolve(false);
        };
        img.onload = () => {
            resolve(true);
        };
        img.src = 'https://www.google.com/favicon.ico?_=' + ((new Date()).getTime());
    });
}
```

If you have a request fail, and `navigator.onLine` is FALSE, you can rest assured, you are actually offline.

If a request succeeds, rest assured, you are effectively online.

Depending on your desired user experience, you may not need much here at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `navigator.onLine` if this is `true` then you're online else offline

Comment: This is largely useless. I disconnect from wifi, or uplug my Ethernet cable on another device and this property is still true despite actually not being online. Still gotta make failing XHR requests

Comment: @DouglasGaskell ohh i didnt knew that, thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @DouglasGaskell I disagree with what you mentioned. `window.navigator.onLine`, this works as expected. You need to listen to `online`/`offline` events to see the change. Please check https://medium.com/@JackPu/how-javascript-detect-the-network-status-42f3a6d85f96 or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine for reference

Comment: @phoenisx I'm not sure what there is to disagree with? Check this property in your browser, disconnect your internet access, and then check it again. It's still true. The doc you linked even states `you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet.` Which pmuch sums up it's usefulness when detecting online/offline states. It also says `if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline`, which, again, shows that it's usefulness is VERY limited.

Comment: @DouglasGaskellI I totally agree with your point. Its use case is limited if you want to track internet connection very accurately. Though in most cases, normal users don't mess with their Network Drivers, Browser preferences, or use Hypervisors, for such cases this value (or event listeners) is the only option to show some descriptive messages, when the user goes offline.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell The statement u made earlier states that the value never changes when WiFi is turned off or on, but it does. I haven't tested it with Ethernet drivers, but I am pretty sure it should work with it as well. Yes, it's true that depending on this variable could be useless at times as for some specific situations the value could be a false positive as mentioned in the doc, but for most cases where the users are browsing on normal systems (not the virtual ones), and their network drivers are not flawed, this value would be true (unless they have some ISP related issue).

Answer (score 0):

request head in request error

```
$.ajax({
    url: /your_url,
    type: "POST or GET",
    data: your_data,
    success: function(result){
      //do stuff
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {

      //detect if user is online and avoid the use of async
        $.ajax({
            type: "HEAD",
            url: document.location.pathname,
            error: function() { 
              //user is offline, do stuff
              console.log("you are offline"); 
              }
         });
    }   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this will return true if network connected

```
function isInternetConnected(){return navigator.onLine;}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a snippet of a helper utility I have. This is namespaced javascript:

```
network: function() {
    var state = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";
    return state;
}
```

You should use this with method detection else fire off an 'alternative' way of doing this. The time is fast approaching when this will be all that is needed. The other methods are hacks.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 answers forthis for two different senarios:-

1. If you are using JavaScript on a website(i.e; or any front-end part)
   The simplest way to do it is:

   ```
   <h2>The Navigator Object</h2>

   <p>The onLine property returns true if the browser is online:</p>

   <p id="demo"></p>

   <script>
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "navigator.onLine is " + navigator.onLine;
   </script>
   ```
2. But if you're using js on server side(i.e; node etc.), You can determine that the connection is lost by making failed XHR requests.

   The standard approach is to retry the request a few times. If it doesn't go through, alert the user to check the connection, and fail gracefully.

Comment: There's difference between being online on a network and having internet available.