# Check device internet connection every minute with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Internet connectivity is checked every minute page was created. However when wifi is off on device the page is redirected to no_internet.hmtl page.  How can we check internet connectivity every time the wifi button is on/off the page should redirect to no_internet.html

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function(){      //loading spinner

    setInterval(
        function(){


          if(window.navigator.onLine){ 

            }else {

                 window.location='./no_internet.html';

                 return false;

            }

     }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function(){

         $.mobile.loading('show', {
        text: 'Chargement en cours...',
        textVisible: true,
        theme: 'a',
        html: "<span class='ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all' ><img width='50px' height='50px' src='http://www.shougun.it/images/loading.gif' /><br><h2>Chargement en cours...</h2></span>"
    });
        },5);    

    });
```

Comment: You can check this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16366985/2065039)** otherwise

Comment: so navigation.online is not trustworthy

Comment: I would say it has quite a much limitations..

Answer (score 0):

```
  var interval=setInterval(function(){ 
        connectionExist(); // function returns a true if an internet connection exists
    }, 1000);

    function connectionExist() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var file = "http://localhost:50041/stackflow/icon1.png"; //URL we specify is the path to the file that we want to check on
        var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

        xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);

        try {
            xhr.send();

            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
                console.log('Connected');
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log('Connection Exist');
                clearInterval(interval);
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:50041/stackflow/noInternet.html";
                return false;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```