# Jquery code to check internet connection and change the button as per result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am looking for jquery/javascript code which checks system internet periodically and change the button.

Same like this http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/navigator.onLine.html

I have code but it not work in all browser. I m looking for ajax kind thing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var tId = setInterval(function () {
                $("#link1, #link2).disabled = !navigator.onLine;
            }, 250);

        var status = navigator.onLine;
        if (status) {
            $("#link1").removeClass('diconnected').addClass('connected');
            $("#link2").removeClass('diconnected').addClass('connected');


        } else {
            $("#link1, #link2,").removeClass('connected').addClass('diconnected');
            $("#link1, #link2,").data('disabled', true);

        }
        }
    </script>
```

This answer [How to detect online/offline event cross-browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181080/how-to-detect-online-offline-event-cross-browser) does not have any code for Ajax, i am looking for ajax

Comment: You make a start, and if you have any programming problems come back and ask for help (searching for possible solutions first), providing your attempted code and clearly stating where, and how, it failed to work.

Comment: Have you tried viewing source on that page? The `navigator.onLine` is right there in line 208

Comment: @DavidThomas: code updated

Comment: Which browser(s) does it fail in, and do they implement the `navigator.online` method?

Comment: Firefox  and mobile browser.And each time i have refresh the page to see change, I am looking something ajax kind.

Comment: Are there any errors reported anywhere? Have you considered adding in alerts (or `console.log()`) to monitor execution? Is the function being called every 250ms?

Comment: https://github.com/HubSpot/offline, or this helpful explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181080/how-to-detect-online-offline-event-cross-browser

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times.