# How to detect every change in the network tab on a site using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm asking about catching the changes that happen in the network tab on chrome when I'm browsing any site, even with change the path name of the url.

Example: `https://www.google.com.eg/` here's the network tab

[image]

And I do a search something will be added to this, my question is How can I catch this using JavaScript in console tab?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324816/how-to-detect-network-state-changes-in-a-chrome-extension might be usefull?

Comment: @Tygo I think that maybe fix my problem somehow.