# Chrome Extension Offline

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-listener, webrequest

I am building a chrome extension with a userinterface build in a Shadow DOM (using Vanilla Javascript).

I have disabled the "normal" pop-up window and inject the User Interface when the User is clicking 
the Chrome Extension icon.

However, I would like the User Interface to be disabled when Chrome is Offline, and reenable when the network connection is back online. I simply made a "offline message" behind the UI - and plan to just "hide" the UI placed in the variable "Canvas"...

I really have a hard time understanding Google's documentation regarding webRequest - it would have been great if they could provide some examples!

I have looked at this question: 
[How to detect network state changes in a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324816/how-to-detect-network-state-changes-in-a-chrome-extension)

This documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onErrorOccurred

- and here:
  -https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

But seem to be stuck! 
I get this error in the console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'onErrorOccurred' of undefined"

- from this (non-working) code(placed in the content script):

```
let target = "https://www.google.com/searchdomaincheck?format=domain&type=chrome"
console.log(target);

console.log({url:`${target}`})

//chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
 showOffline(), {url:`${target}`} 
);

webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
RemoveshowOffline(), {url:`${target}`}  
);

function showOffline() {
  Canvas.style.display = "none";
}

function RemoveshowOffline() {
  Canvas.style.display = "inline-grid";
}
```

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of chrome API. You need a background script.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm!
Not sure this is the issue here - I have a background script also - just tried the  code in the background script -and get this error: 
"error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined" 
- am I simply writing the URL wrong?

Comment: I can't help without seeing the new code.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out  wOxxOm - that's highly appreciated!!! I think I found a different (working) solution - see my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I think I am overcomplicating things here I think I found a better solution using

window.addEventListener('offline', (event) 
and 
window.addEventListener('online', (event) 
from the content script. Seems like the 'simple' and correct way to solve this!

Comment: Does this handle when there are DNS errors? E.g. connected to wifi but requests are timing out?

Comment: I do not think so. This is a very basic way of assessing network status. I would definitely expect this check to fail in some edge cases. But for the usecases I work with it's usually fine.

Answer (score 0):

Working with manifest version 3 extension, I failed trying to subscribe on 'offline' event from background service worker. I tried it like so:

```
self.addEventListener('offline', cb)
```

And I came up with:

```
navigator.connection.addEventListener('change', changeHandler)

function changeHandler() { 
    const isOnline = navigator.onLine
    // do your stuff
}
```

This event triggers every time connection has been lost. I assume, because estimated effective round-trip time of the current connection changes in disconnected/connected state.

However, it is an experimental technology and seems doesn't work for Firefox and Safari extensions. More info [NetworkInformation/change_event doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/change_event)