# "Offline" event not get fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have an event listener attached to `offline` event in javascript. This is working fine when ethernet cable is unplugged or set `offline` mode in debugger but not working in other scenarios like turning on AIRPLANE MODE or disconnecting wifi.

`$(window).on('offline',function(){alert('offline')});`

Comment: offline event implementation is very browser specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181080/how-to-detect-online-offline-event-cross-browser#4813406 
edit: what browser are you using? try to check navigator.onLine to see if the status changes when you disconnect the wifi

Comment: @KarmanKertesz event is firing when cable unplugged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After years, I've found a more reliable way to attach an event for connection changes

`navigator` object has a `connection` which in turn has an `onchange` property which expects a callback method to be executed whenever a connection change occurs

```
navigator.connection.onchange=function()
    {
        if(navigator.onLine)
        {
            console.log('Connection is okay')
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Connection lost')
        }
    }
```

But...According to MDN, the `navigator.onLine` could return false positives

> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local
> area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions
> return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when
> it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value
> necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. You could
> be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is
> running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters
> that are always "connected." Therefore, if you really want to
> determine the online status of the browser, you should develop
> additional means for checking.

Comment: No "navigator.connection" in Safari 13

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use navigator.onLine

Comment: `navigator.onLine` is just a property. how to capture that event

Comment: use conditions instead of eventListener

Comment: you suggest to use setInterval? if so its not a best practice