# Javascript window.addeventlistener not firing in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, addeventlistener

i'm trying to detect whether the browser is connected to the internet or not using javascript. my implementation works for me on both Edge and chrome but does not works when i try to test in on another pc.

i tried clearing cache, cookie and even reinstall my browsers thinking it could be cache related but still it works on my machine but not when i try it on any other. the issue is strictly related to chrome as edge seems to work fine on any other pc.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
    <script type="text/javascript">

       // Checking connectivity - Displays message and play sounds if lose
window.addEventListener('offline', () => {

console.log("offline");

});
window.addEventListener('online', () => {
console.log("online");

});


    </script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>


  </body>
</html>
```

i wrote the above test html, which again works on chrome on my machine but does not for others. the expected result should be print offline in console when you disconnect the pc from internet and online when reconnected without the need to refresh the page.

Comment: Try to wrap those window.addEventListener calls with additional load event. Also see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events) about the usage and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/online_event) where compatibility is confirmed, if you were wondering.

Comment: Instead of unplugging your connection go to F12 -> network -> OFFLINE
works like a charm

Comment: @MikeSar thanks for the feedback, i tried that but still no  luck. weirdly it works on my machine but not when i try it on another pc. browsers version are the and the setting are identical

Comment: @Raimonds i see, but the whole point is to be able to detect it  in real life. when the wifi connection drop and the browser is not longer connected. this event should fire.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181080/how-to-detect-online-offline-event-cross-browser. This is a related post.

Comment: In this case I think most reliable way is to set up some sort of long polling with server.

Comment: Could you give som more details about the specs of the other pc you tested on? I tested your page on my own computer and it worked for me. Could be an outdated version of chrome or a weird os/browser combination.

Comment: @JensVæverHartfelt  all the other pc are identical to mine, same brand, same specs and operating system. the chrome version is Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Odd! Is it in a corporate environment? Perhaps some security software is preventing chrome from detecting network abailability.

Comment: @JensVæverHartfelt indeed, ill see if there is a work around for this.

Comment: As others have said, polling might be an ok option. If you set up an endpoint that just sends a 200 OK, it should be okay to just check that endpoint continually every 5 seconds or so.

Comment: @JensVæverHartfelt   ill give that solution a go.. thank you all for the feedback. much appreciated