# Dialog box if there is no internet connection using jquery or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dialog, internet-connection

If there is no internet connection  ,it will show some error message using dialog box like " No internet connection"  without using java .I need to display using jquery or ajax script alert...

Comment: Possible duplicate 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline

Comment: i need to show some dialog box in my mobile app if there is no internet connection.dont bother about button...if i am in offline

Answer (score 13):

In your JQuery ajax call, you could use the following and then query the status code of the error. Note that the status code will be 0 if they are offline, but you can also query other status codes (see below for a list):

```
$.ajax({
    //your ajax options
    error: function(statusCode, errorThrown) {
        if (statusCode.status == 0) {
            alert("you're offline");
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a list of status codes you could also catch for reference: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40132

Comment: what is x ,e where should i apply

Comment: x is the HTTP Status Code of the error and e is the error object, sorry I'll update the names in my code. You should put the error inside your existing jQuery ajax call. If you post your actual code I can show you exactly where it needs to go. Take a look at the error function here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Status can be 0 for multiple other reasons than a network failure.

Comment: 0 could also mean that the firewall was blocked ( I know this from personal experience)

Answer (score 4):

```
function isOnline() {
    var online = navigator.onLine;    // Detecting the internet connection
    if(online) {
       // do your stuff
    } else {
       alert('You\'re Offline now...');
    }
}
```