# Connectivity status in Iphone using sencha app

Tags: javascript, ios, sencha-touch

I am a newbie in sencha and using sencha touch 2.0 to develop an app that is compatible with IOS.
In have a functionality like when using the app in phone, when no connectivity I need to display an alert. I tried with window.navigator.onLine. But it worked in browser not in Iphone. Kindly let me know is there any other way to implement this using sencha's library?
Even `navigator.network.isReachable("http://www.google.com", reachableCallback, {});` is not working.

Can you please help??

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to detect that the Internet connection is offline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

Comment: network.isReachable will work only if you're using PhoneGap.

Comment: @TDeBailleul: That's not really a valid duplicate in this day and age; that duplicate is lonnnnnnnnng out of date.

Comment: Yeah, I figured but I can't remove the closing vote, can I ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul: Unfortunately not. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use

```
Ext.device.Connection.isOnline()
```

More info here http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Connection

Comment: It doesn't work.  
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Connection' of undefined.

Comment: include require : Ext.device.Connection in your app

Answer (score 0):

In Sencha touch 2.2 I tried Ext.device.Connection.isOnline(), but its always return true either in offline/online. So i tried this one

```
navigator.onLine
```

its working for me in my ipad