# I want to add a facebook functionality of displaying a message when my user loses the internet connection

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: How to detect that the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

In facebook, when you loose the internet connection, you see a message "No internet connection. Try again?" and you are changed from online to offline. I want that in my website. How can I do that?

Comment: Send a ping to the server.  If no response, then they are offline and alert them using Javascript.

Comment: As of HTML5, you can use [`window.navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine), though not fully compatible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, but I would probably handle it differently.  It just sends a query to a page on your server every 15 seconds.  If the query fails, then it is probably offline (either you or the server).

```
function checkOnline(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
    }).done(function( html ) {
        if(html=='ok')
            setTimeout('checkOnline()',15000);
        else
            alert('Error');
    }).fail(function(){
        alert('Offline');
    });
}
```

test.php

```
<?php exit('ok'); ?>
```

I would personally attach a fail function to my other Ajax or polling queries.  If those failed, I would trigger the Offline message and cease further polling or queries until the page was reloaded or after a certain time interval.  No sense in just polling the server for the heck of it.

Comment: Thanks . what about changing the user from online to offline in my MySql database. Is it possible. How does facebook do that?

Answer (score 3):

Run a periodical ajax request to your server. If the request fails, the ajax engine would call a "fail" callback.

But in real life, you would probably attach a "fail" javascript callback to all requests to server side, and it would fire upon a failed request.