# Make image update/change based on website availability

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is what i am trying to do.

Lets say i have a table, and one of the parts of the table is for telling the user if the website listed is active and running or not.

What i am trying to do is make it so an image updates based on if the website is active or not.

So if the website is active the picture in the table would be active.jpg , or if the website is down, the picture would be down.jpg.. etc etc.

So for an overall basic example :

this is what i would like someone to see when they connect to my site.

```
Website      Active         Link
-------------------------------------------
Google.com   active.jpg     www.google.com

Yahoo.com    down.jpg       www.yahoo.com
```

Is this possible? and easy to implement? I have been scouring the internet to find a solution, and cant find anything, hoping maybe someone on here has something i can at least use to get started in the right direction with this.

Comment: How are you defining in your table whether the site is active or not? 1 for active, 0 for in-active?

Comment: In the table i would like it to be a different picture based on if the site is alive or not.

Comment: You need to use ajax (or maybe websockets) to ask php to check each site. You can't check them from JavaScript.

Comment: You may have a look at this question, I think this will give you some pointers; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline

Comment: Please define **active**

Comment: Active as in is the website working. can i connect to it, does it give me a response.