# How to help protect for irregular internet connection in a Backbone application? Is there a solution like in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, synchronization, meteor, offline

I am building applications that are used on a touch screen in an educational environment. The applications gather data from user input. The data is then send to a server. There are multiple units, and whilst exact synchronisation is not paramount, the gathered data (along with other data collection from another source) will be combined and distributed back to the touch screen applications.

The applications are being build in Backbone with initial data loaded from a single JSON document. The JSON document is parsed from a remote MySQL database, which is downloaded (along with assets) on initialisation.

Whilst when possible the app should send new data back to the remote mySQL DB as soon as it is gathered, this may not always be possible and I need to collect the data so as to send it when I can.

My first thoughts are that storing everything in localstorage and syncing whenever possible (clearing the localstorage each time a successful sync takes place) is the way to go.

Over the bank holiday weekend, I have been playing [meteor.js](http://meteor.com/), and I think that maybe if I write my localstorage solution I will be reinventing the wheel, and a tricky wheel at that. It seems that Meteor.js has a way of mimicking a database offline, in order to fake instant updating.

My question is: How can I use a similar technique to add some offline protection? Is there a JS framework, or backbone plugin I can utilise, or a technique I can tap into?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) to save your models and collections to the local storage, while the connection is offline.

Detecting if your user is offline is as easy as noticing that your xhr requests are failing. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/189443/1448860e).

To combine these two.

1. When you suspect the user is offline (an ajax request to your backend gets no response), switch Backbone.localStorage and store everything there. Inform the user!
2. When the user gets Internet connectivity again, save any changes from localStorage to the server. Inform the user again!

Voilà!

Comment: The problem with that is that I would have to manually switch from using localstorage to syncing with a server. The network connection is intermittent, if I lose connection after starting to manually sync, can I then resync with all of my data intact?