# How to check if an active internet connection exists?

Tags: javascript

Normally one would use `navigator.onLine`. This works fine for 90% of scenarios.

What about if you are connected to a Wi-Fi network but have 100% packet loss? The `onLine` property described above will tell you that you are connected as your connection to the network is fine, but you have absolutely no **internet** connection. Is there any way to get around this?

I simply want to check if a working internet connection is present.

Comment: Determining the existence of a connection to a network endpoint is fundamentally problematic. When the network is flaky external to the client device, nothing in the device really knows what's going on.

Comment: Check out this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline