# Provide proper message if email not sent due to slow internet or no internet connection

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am trying find solution for providing proper message in case of net connection lost or no internet at all, I am using codeigniter to send mail and smpt protocol. This the code i am using

```
<?php
function sending_mail(){
        $mail_config = Array (
                   'mailtype' =>'html',
                   'protocol' => 'smtp',
                   'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                   'smtp_port' => 465,
                   'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
                   'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
                   'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
                   );
           $this->load->library('email',$mail_config);
           $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
           $this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'InnoLogiq LLP');
           $this->email->to('receipientemail@gmail.com');
           $message = 'mymessage';
           $this->email->subject("mysubject");
           $this->email->message($message);
           if($this->email->send()){
           $data['flag']="success" ;
           $data['msg']="Email sent";
           $this->load->view('templates/header1'); 
           $this->load->view('company/contact_us',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
           }
           else{
            $data['msg']="Here I want mesage but its showing error, due to net connection";
            $data['flag']='error';
            print_r("Sorry! mail not send");
            $this->load->view('company/contact_us',$data);
           }
    }
```

I tried show_error also tried removing that, but if my connection is slow or it fails to send email or fails to upload attachments then it simply shows dozens of errors I want to get rid of those errors and need to provide proper response to end user. Any suggestion please....

Comment: You could use `JS`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline

Comment: No that is not my case. there must be some in build function in codeigniter to avoid error messages. Anyway thanks for the reply