# Detect internet connectivity using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if internet is available or not when the web page loads. I want to do this in order to:

- disable like buttons request if offline, during development
- load local links if no network, otherwise load from HTTP
- call more data from server in appcache based offline apps only if user is online

How do I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/javascript-how-to-detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline got alot of examples for the offline checking question.

Answer (score 1):

The `window.navigator` object has an `online` property that you can use:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine

Alternatively you can make a quick Ajax request and check the error code you receive.