# Angular js , How to check if user has internet connection, before calling url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to check the Internet-connection before calling myurl

```
$scope.clicked=function(id){
 if($window.navigator.onLine){ 
         $window.open('myurl='+id);
         }else{
            alert('offline');
         }
};
```

Comment: Why not just handle a 404 error?

Comment: @Davin Tryon could you please explain

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: i need to check  the Internet connection every time i try to call my web server

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/189443/2460773

Comment: @Nistan Baleli I have seen several solutions, but in my case it does not work

Comment: use window.navigator.onLine not $window.navigator.onLine (don't use $ before window).

Answer (score -1):

```
    You can use window.navigator.onLine but no need to write $ before window.
 It works fine if you have only one network connection but it shows online even if you are not connected to internet but with any internal network like loopback adapter too. So best option to check connectivity with internet is html5 Web Socket but itonly works on windows 8 so if you don't have windows 8 then you can use html5 EventSource interface. you can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource
```

Comment: Hallo  Ankit, I am developing a mobile app with AngularJS, the thing is, I need to check whether internet is available or not, had to work for all browsers