# How to load a dynamically created HTML page in my app when going back online?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, web-applications, html5-appcache

I have created an app using jQuery mobile. There is a page in an app which has a reference to an external webpage located on the internet. Now when the user is not connected to the internet, the page in the app will show an error that you are not connected to the internet.

I want to do something so that the most recent content is shown in that page. When the user connects back to the internet and tries to open the page, the page should automatically update. I read something about appcache but I am not able to do it.

Comment: Perhaps [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+detect+internet+connection) could be a starting point for research?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect that the Internet connection is offline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline)