# Switch javascript script when users are online or offline

Tags: javascript, html, navigator

I have a question about Javascript.
I create a web page (HTML+Javascript) and want to run *script#1* if the user is online, or *script#2* else.
I have a small and bad idea:

```
if(navigator.online) { /*here I want: <script src="script#1.js"></script>*/}else {/*here I want: <script src="script#2.js"></script>*/}
```

Have you got a better idea?

Comment: that looks like a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 Application Cache API specifies

```
navigator.onLine
```

it should work on major browsers.

Comment: Hi, maybe you don't understand: if you are online do script#1, else do script#2 (with if-then-else instruction).
But how I create this idea?

Comment: ok, got you now. you mean INCLUDE that script.
But it seems a bit overkill, why don't you just have your both file loaded and execute the one you want depending on being online or not ?