# how to judge client's network off-line or online use JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
if(window.navigator.onLine==true){
    alert（"connect success"）
 }else{
    alert（"fail"）
}
```

`window.navigator.onLine` always return true whatever in off-line or online.any other methods to solve this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood issue correctly, Its already answered Here :
[Detect that the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

We can mark this duplicate for same Question.