# Ignoring particular javascript files

Tags: javascript

in my website i have embedded accuweather widget:

```
    <a href="http://www.accuweather.com/pl/pl/gdask/275174/weather-forecast/275174" class="aw-widget-legal"></a>
    <div id="awcc1459281264171" class="aw-widget-current" style="float:right; width: 479px; height: 180px; margin:12px;" data-locationkey="275174" data-unit="c" data-language="pl" data-useip="false" data-uid="awcc1459281264171"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script>
```

today i realized that i didnt pay last internet provider bill and instead of `lanunch.js` i got this stuff loaded:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=https://ebok.upc.pl/blokada">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("document.location='https://ebok.upc.pl/blokada';", 1000);   
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

saying internet connection has been blocked. Unfortunatelly this replaced by provider file is generating error on my webpage, and makes it non functional:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <             launch.js:1
```

question is - what would be the best workaround for that? mean how to disable widget if there is no internet connection etc?

thx for all responses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

Comment: nah, connection is not offline!

Comment: so what makes the widget to show this?