# How to hide any div inside html form if internet is not availaible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Guys I would like to know if it is possible to hide the div if the internet is not availaible.
Here is the code

```js
if(navigator.onLine) { 
     //show
}
else{
//Hide
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: @Huangism no help. How do I hide div element?

Comment: @mark22 have you asked google? while I didn't vote you down but your question clearly shows lack of research or attempts made to solve the issue. Just google how to hide div with jquery

Comment: Please spend the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. This is another of your questions that simply does not provide enough details or a specific enough problem statement. Of course you can do what you ask and the first obvious question would be what went wrong when you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the internet is connected or not by

```
window.onload = checkInternetConnection;
function checkInternetConnection() {
  var isOnLine = navigator.onLine;
   if (isOnLine) {
      alert(connectionMessage);
   } else {
     alert(noConnectionMessage);
   }
}
```

so if `isOffline`, You can use jquery to hide that specific div like

```
$('.div_class_name').hide();
```

and
if online, use

```
$('.div_class_name').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if(navigator.onLine) { 
           $("#element-id").show();
        }
        else{
          $("#element-id").hide();
        } 
    });.
```