# How to show alert when internet connection is gone in html

Tags: javascript, html

Which function in html can I use to make it ...
That when I open website and become offline so it show alert that "You are offline please turn on internet connection to run website."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var online = navigator.onLine;
         if (online == false) 
            {
                    alert("Sorry, we currently do not have Internet access.");
                    location.reload(); 
            }
```

Comment: but how you will watch `online` variable

Answer (score 3):

You can use `window` `offline` event

```
window.addEventListener('offline', function(event){
    alert("You are offline please turn on internet connection to run website");
});
```