# How to check for an internet connection in an Expo React Native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo app using the [Managed workflow](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/managed-vs-bare/). The app needs to check whether an internet connection is available.

- I can't `import { NetInfo } from 'react-native'` because [that's deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html).
- I can't use [react-native-community/react-native-netinfo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo) because that uses native libraries, and you can't do that with an Expo managed app.
- I could eject, in order to use the above, but it doesn't seem like I should need to do that just to check if there's an internet connection.
- I can't use [`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) because that global variable doesn't seem to be available.
- I could make a trivial HTTP request to Google or my own server or whatever, and see if I get a response, but that only tests a connection to one site, and also it takes time and uses bandwidth.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do I have to take it out to use the netinfo module when I'm using Expo?

Comment: @hongdevelop You can't add in your own native modules or use `react-native link` with an Expo managed project. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and

Comment: The netinfo module can be used without adding modules.

Comment: @hongdevelop Which NetInfo module? The one that’s deprecated?

Comment: NetInfo of react-native

Comment: You can also use netinfo in expo because you can use the basic module of react-native in expo.

Comment: @hongdevelop That's the one that's deprecated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `NetInfo` of `react-native`.

Yes, it is deprecated because they are planning on removing it in the next version of `react-native` in favor of the community version. However, it is completely functional and can still be used for now, just make sure to check for breaking changes when the next versions of `Expo SDK` are released.

It is likely that Expo will bring it into their managed workflow when `react-native` removes it, or provide an alternative that won't require ejecting from Expo.

Answer (score 11):

Expo SDK 34 has already included `NetInfo API`.

You can check their documentation for SDK 34 here https://docs.expo.io/versions/v34.0.0/sdk/netinfo

Here is the link for documentation for [latest version](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/netinfo/)

Answer (score 7):

2022 here, had the same issue before ejecting expo, we used expo-network

```
import * as Network from 'expo-network';
```

and use it like so

```
const networkState = await Network.getNetworkStateAsync();
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/network/#networkgetnetworkstateasync

Answer (score 4):

It's really hard to define if a device has internet or not [stackoverflow.com/a/189443/7602110](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189443/7602110), just by having failed XHR requests you can say that you have internet, but isn't that reliable. You would like to check with some reliables websites like **google.com**, I have come with a work-around but I don't actually recommend it, is up to you.

You can use the [`Linking.canOpenUrl()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#canopenurl) method from React Native itself, which will return a Promise object. When it is determined whether or not the given URL can be handled, the promise is resolved and the first parameter is whether or not it can be opened.

Then add a request and if the response status it's `200` you should have internet.

[image]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet, Linking } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    connection: false,
    url: 'https://google.com',
  };

  checkInternt = () => {
    Linking.canOpenURL(this.state.url).then(connection => {
      if (!connection) {
        this.setState({ connection: false });
      } else {
        fetch(this.state.url).then(res =>
          this.setState({ connection: res.status !== 200 ? false : true })
        );
      }
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkInternt();
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    this.setState({
      url:
        this.state.url === 'https://google.com'
          ? 'http://someweirdurlthatdoesntwork.com'
          : 'https://google.com',
    });
    this.checkInternt();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Connection:
          <Text style={{ color: this.state.connection ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
            {`   ${this.state.connection}`}
          </Text>
        </Text>
        <Text>{this.state.url.replace(/\https?:\/\//g, '')}</Text>
        <Button onPress={this.handlePress} title="Change server url" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Check the snack: [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/check-internet](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/check-internet)

Answer (score 0):

NetInfo is removed from Expo sdk 48. You should install it via `@react-native-community/netinfo` package