# Get internet connection status in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest

I want to test if the user has an active internet connection.

I know we can do it with navigator.Online, but I don't think it works when the user has a limited WiFi network.

I need to show a popup if the user has been disconnected/has a limited WiFi network

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

Answer (score 0):

## XHR Requests

Try making an XHR request to the same website itself (or maybe even a couple of XHR requests), and check if it fails, and if it does, you can safely conclude that the user does not have an active internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one npm package [ng-connection-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-connection-service)

after that you can easily use next code into your root app component:

```
constructor (private connectionService: ConnectionService) {
        this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe((isConnected: boolean) => {
            if (!isConnected) {
                alert('oops you have no Internet connection');
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function like this :

```
const checkConnection = () => fetch('https://google.com')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('HTTP status ' + response.status);
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then(response => 'online')
        .catch(error => 'offline');
```

And use it like this:

```
const isOnline = await checkConnection() === 'online';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a native way that's supported [almost everywhere](https://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status):

```
const isOnline = ('onLine' in navigator) ? navigator.onLine : true
```

And a pair of event listeners:

```
window.addEventListener('online', () => {
    isOnline = true
})

window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
    isOnline = false
})
```