# Check Is Internet Connectivity Active Using Javascript & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a script using javascript or query to check is internet connection still active on every 1 second ?

So was wrote some codes using [PING.JS](https://github.com/alfg/ping.js/tree/master) but I have a problem. My script sends 1 PING request on every 1 second and the server will response within 1 second, but My problem is I want to code if for any reason server's reply will not receive within 60 seconds then it will show me an alert. Also, I want to store data on variable how many PING request was received server's reply successfully? [I am providing my script link. Please check and tell me where I was wrong](https://476606.playcode.io).

> **https://476606.playcode.io**

Comment: Please embed your code in the question :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, there's an experimental browser API called the "Network Information API".

You can use it like this:

```
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
var type = connection.effectiveType;

function updateConnectionStatus() {
  console.log("Connection type changed from " + type + " to " + connection.effectiveType);
  type = connection.effectiveType;
}

connection.addEventListener('change', updateConnectionStatus);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API

It's got reasonably good support on mobile browsers, but not so on desktop browsers.
This will show you the currently supported browsers:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=netinfo

Comment: Nice solution, and much better than DDOSing your server with requests every second

Comment: @JashminBezos don't. It's a really bad idea. Why do you feel that you need to do that?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Due to some Ads serving requirements I want to check it on every 1 second.

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to rinse ad revenue. Good luck.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't using Adsence Ads. I want to use my own Ads network. So I really want to check it on every 1 second . **Please give me solution.**

Comment: @JashminBezos are you looking to see if your AD server is online in general or just accessible by the user's browser at the time?