# How to see if user is connected to internet or NOT?

Tags: python, django, request

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to implement a feature that ,`If user is connected to internet then everything works fine BUT if user is not connected to internet then show a message like "You're not Connected to Internet".

**What have i tried**

- I also tried channels but then i think internet connection are far away from **Django-channels**.
- I also tried this :

  ```
  url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
  timeout = 5
  try:
      request = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
      print("Connected to the Internet")
  except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
      print("No INTERNET")
  ```

But it is keep showing me :

> 'Response' object has no attribute 'META'

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/d42dc3f3c63edf0e2eb08f9297705ed9333c4357/statsmodels/datasets/utils.py#L274-L281) is an implementation that uses `urllib.request.urlopen`.

Comment: a simple workaround will be to use js... check ---- " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline "

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to know whether you're connected to the internet. In fact it is not even clear what this means. It depends a lot on the context.

In many practical cases it means, that your network setup is setup such, that you can access a DNS server and that you can access at least one machine on the internet.

You could just use one known url like for example `"https://google.com"` or `"https://stackoverflow.com"`.

However this means that:

- your test will fail if given service is for any reason down
- you create requests to a server that isn't yours.

If you know, that the application should access your special web service, then you could use the url of your special web service:

`url = "https://your_special_webservice.yourdomain"`

Side information:

If you put the code in your question into a django view, that handles http requests, then you should probably write something like:

```
request = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
```

instead of

```
response = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
```

Otherwise you will overwrite the `request` object, of your django view
and this is probably what provoked your error message:
'Response' object has no attribute 'META'

Comment: You're right, BUT now i think i should use `JavaScript` for check the weather of Internet Connection .

Comment: using javascript will move the test for internet conection from the web server into your web browser. depending on what you want to achieve exactly, this might be a good idea. (You might want to adapt the question to reflect this)

Comment: Yes, Thank you Very Much for you  Effort