# Force Leaflet tile refresh when network connectivity restored

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

We've got a React app using Leaflet maps and our users can sometimes be in areas that have spotty coverage and they can lose connection for a period of time.  When this happens they can pan/zoom on the map and get blank tiles.  I would like to make a call to retrieve those missing tiles when the connection is restored.  So far I've tried `invalidateSize`, looping through each layer and calling redraw and even getting the center of the map and calling `setView` with a slightly different `centerpoint` and nothing is making the map update to retrieve the missing tiles.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to hook into the fact that coverage was broken, and restored.  However, you can set a function to run periodically (polling) to see if the connection exists.  There's some methods on how to do that here: [Detect if the internet connection if offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline).  Say in the base script, you set an interval going:

```js
let onlineTracker = true;

setInterval(() => {
  if(navigator.onLine && !onlineTracker) {
    map.invalidateSize();
    onlineTracker = true
  } else {
    onlineTracker = false;
  }
}, 1000) // every 1 second
```

So what you're doing is maintaining the online status with `onlineTracker`.  You periodically ask whether `navigator.onLine`.  If its offline, set the `onlineTracker` to false.  You keep polling.  As soon as `navigator.onLine` returns true again, you `map.invalidateSize`, which will refetch the tiles, and set the `onlineTracker` back to false so that every following iteration of the interval hits the `else` block and does nothing.