# How to catch iframe src load error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am loading iframe source `document.getElementById('iframeID').src = source here`  in function and that function is called again every second until my requirement is fulfilled.

When internet disconnected in between this process I get status cancelled in network panel and process continue when internet connected again (my requirement). so how can I catch this error and show error message to user.

I have already tried jQuery to assign `src` and catch error but that didn't work and affected my required functionality.

I also tried using try/catch but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820206/14104

Answer (score 0):

You can capture load errors by adding an event listener to the tag. Here's an example doing the same for an image, using a URL that doesn't resolve.

```js
const image = document.getElementById("img");
const invalidUrl = "https://localhost:1000/doesNotExist.png";
img.src = invalidUrl;

image.addEventListener("error", event => {
  console.log(`${event.type}: Loading image`);
});
```

```html
<img id="img" />
```

I'd also recommend building in some functionality to suspend checking every second if you go offline, as @epascarello mentioned.

```js
// resume automatic checks
window.addEventListener('online', () => console.log('Became online'));
// suspend automatic checks
window.addEventListener('offline', () => console.log('Became offline'));
```