# Check connection loss in JavaScript on the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I referred to this [Detect the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline) question to find out how to check if the browser is offline or online.
So I used **window.navigator.onLine** to find that out.

The problem is that, no matter what I do, **window.navigator.onLine** is always **true**.

I am using brave browser, but I'm not sure if that's related to the issue, it's chromium based.

I'm on Ubuntu Linux, desktop.

I just want to detect when the browser becomes offline to show a small message *"connection lost"*.

In react the code looks as follows:

```js
const online = window.navigator.onLine
  useEffect(() => {
    if (online) return
    console.log("Connection lost!")
  }, [online])
```

try to toggle your wifi on and on to see the console logs

Here's a stack blitz instance to try it out, it's a pretty small code, ([Click me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jfzqzp?file=src/App.js))

Comment: Need to use the event listener for this: window.addEventListener('online', () => { ...});. Inside the callback setstate to check online off-line toggle

Comment: Well that code won't run when you toggle your wifi, react has no reason to re-render the component?

Comment: Yes, in browser it's always true

Comment: @Bergi, it will render a [snack bar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/), but this is just a demo, to console.log instead of rendering something

Comment: Check out here https://www.positronx.io/react-function-component-detect-internet-network-status-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

> The property sends updates whenever the browser's ability to connect to the network changes. The update occurs when the user follows links or when a script requests a remote page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine

So the value won't update unless you make a request of some sort.

There are also some implementation specific notes on the same url.

> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true.

In other words, if there is any sort of network access it will be `true`, even if you are not connected to the internet.

So the best way to check this is probably to just make a request to an API endpoint or other resource that is only available while online and base your status on if the request was successful or not. Since in most cases just being "online" isn't worth much if your API is inaccessible this would probably provide better   information to your users as well.

Comment: Thanks. So there's no way to "watch" for such an event (regardless of being able to access the internet),

Comment: There is an event for this as Murtaza Hussain noted in the other answer. It still won't fire until there there is a request of some sort happening though and still has the same specifics for Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use the event listener for this: `window.addEventListener('online', () => { ...});`.

Inside the callback for listener, do `setState` to check **online off-line toggle**.

here is small `hook` i created in `reactjs` to handle online offline states:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// toastr alert messages 
import { showOffline, showOnline } from 'utils/alerts';

const useNetworkStatus = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);

  async function isOnline() {
    // if its offline and to check if window?.navigator is supported.
    if (!window?.navigator?.onLine) {
      setState(false);
      return false;
    }

    // Failover case:
    // navigator.onLine cannot be trusted: there's situation where you appear to be online (connect to a network with no internet)
    // but still cannot access the internet.
    // So to fix: we request to our own origin to avoid CORS errors
    const url = new URL(window.location.origin);
    //  with random value to prevent cached responses
    url.searchParams.set('rand', Date.now());

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url.toString(), { method: 'HEAD' });
      setState(true);
      return response.ok;
    } catch {
      setState(false);
      return false;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const setOnlineOnVisibleChange = async () => {
      // if its page is visible and state was offline
      if (!document?.hidden && !state) {
        if (await isOnline()) showOnline();
      }
    };
    // on visiting the page again if the state is offline and network is online, then show online alert
    if ('hidden' in document)
      document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', setOnlineOnVisibleChange, false);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('visibilitychange', setOnlineOnVisibleChange, false);
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function changeStatus() {
      if (await isOnline()) showOnline();
      else showOffline();
    }

    // Listen for the page to be finished loading
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      // if its offline
      if (!isOnline()) showOffline();
    });

    window.addEventListener('online', changeStatus);
    window.addEventListener('offline', changeStatus);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('online', changeStatus);
      window.removeEventListener('offline', changeStatus);
    };
  }, []);
};

export default useNetworkStatus;
```

Comment: a great way to improve this hook is to seperate the hook logic from the UI, we can make it return an object like this: `const {isOnline, isOffline} = useConnectionChecker()`, then we can render any custom thing based on the isOnline or the isOffline properties

Comment: That sounds good, I'll modify the code, so that addresses the separation of concern